# Using ChangeListener in @ActionMethod

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have created an application, it shows table of accounts. What I want is when I select any row from this table and press `delete` Button, hibernate will change field state to 0 in `AccountTable` (0 - stands for deleted account, 1 - for active).

For now, I can't incorporate `ChangeListener` into `@ActionMethod`

```
public ChangeListener<PositionAccount> deleteAccount = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        DeleteAccount input = new DeleteAccount();
        input.setAccountId(newValue.getId());

        service.deleteAccount(input,context.getTaskView(),result -> {

        });
    };
```

into

```
@ActionMethod(ACTION_DELETE_ACCOUNT)
    public void deleteAccount(){
        DeleteAccount input = new DeleteAccount();

        service.deleteAccount(input, context.getTaskView(), result -> {
            model.getAccounts().addAll(result.getAccount());
            tv_loro_nostro_accounts.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
        });
    }
```

I guess input in last code should be `ID` that is set on first code. How to put these two parts together?

And what hibernate methods should I use to update table? Thanks